# Haskell - Recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to make a card game that two players show there cards and the one with the highest rank wins and takes the card.(War Card Game). The trouble i am having is running the whole game, to see the final result of who the winner is. I have made the code that can do one round of the game:

```
type ComparisonRule = Card -> Card -> Bool
type RoundRule = ([Card],[Card]) -> ([Card],[Card])

standardComparison :: ComparisonRule
standardComparison (Card r1 _) (Card r2 _)
    | r1 > r2  = True
    |otherwise = False

roundWithoutWar :: ComparisonRule -> RoundRule
roundWithoutWar f (x:xs,y:ys)
        |f x y     = (xs ++ [x] ++ [y],ys)
        |f y x     = (xs,ys ++ [y] ++ [x])
        |otherwise = (xs,ys)
```

I use

```
standardRound :: RoundRule
standardRound =  roundWithoutWar standardComparison
to run one round of the game.
```

I am trying to make a full game function that would run the rounds in recursion until someone wins(the winner is the person with the most cards):

```
fullGame :: RoundRule -> ([Card],[Card]) -> [([Card],[Card])]
fullGame r  ([],[]) = [([],[])]
fullGame r ([],y:ys)        = [([],y:ys)]
fullGame r (x:xs,[])      = [(x:xs,[])]
fullGame r (x:xs,y:ys)       = (x:xs,y:ys) : fullGame ( r (x:xs,y:ys))
```

"r" being the single round function (StandardRound) However, i get an error when i try to run the full game function

```
 War_Project_2.hs:138:46:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[([Card], [Card])]’
                with actual type ‘([Card], [Card]) -> [([Card], [Card])]’
    Probable cause: ‘fullGame’ is applied to too few arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
      ‘fullGame (r (x : xs, y : ys))’
    In the expression: (x : xs, y : ys) : fullGame (r (x : xs, y : ys))

War_Project_2.hs:138:57:
    Couldn't match type ‘([Card], [Card])’
                   with ‘([Card], [Card]) -> ([Card], [Card])’

    Expected type: RoundRule
      Actual type: ([Card], [Card])
    Possible cause: ‘r’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the first argument of ‘fullGame’, namely ‘(r (x : xs, y : ys))’
    In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
      ‘fullGame (r (x : xs, y : ys))’
```

The point free function i tried to write to run the fullgame is:

```
simpleFullGame ::([Card],[Card]) -> [([Card],[Card])]
simpleFullGame = fullGame simpleRound
```

Comment: `fullGame ( r (x:xs,y:ys))` should be `fullGame r ( r (x:xs,y:ys))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a helpful function that almost does exactly what you are looking for.

```
  iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

This can successively apply your `RoundRule` function which is essentially an update function. All you have to do is stop when the game is done.

```
done :: ([Card],[Card]) -> Bool
```

Then when you have that function your full game will be.

```
fullGame roundRule initState = takeWhile (not . done) (iterate roundRule initState)
```

Since Haskell is lazy it won't generate at game states beyond the end state.